# CIContext returns a nil CGImageRef when using a CIRandomGenerator filter

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-image, cifilter

I'm trying to get the output of the CoreImage CIRandomGenerator filter, with the following code:

```
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

CIFilter *randomNoise = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIRandomGenerator"];
[randomNoise setDefaults];

CIImage *output = randomNoise.outputImage;

// This returns nil
CGImageRef ref = [context createCGImage:output
                               fromRect:output.extent];
self.photoView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];
CGImageRelease(ref);
```

However, the createCGImage:fromRect: always returns a nil CGImageRef.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is extent? I have a feeling it may be infinite, so you need to crop it to the area you want.

Comment: That's correct. Add this as an answer and I'll accept it right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be sure to crop the `extent` so that it's not infinite.